# Choosing a Riemannian-metric such that a submanifold $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is totally geodesic.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm currently working through Palais' Morse Theory on Hilbert manifolds and looking for a reference / proof for the following:

[image]

If anybody could help me, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: My initial idea would be to look at a tubular neighbourhood of $V$, then choose a metric $g$ on $V$ and extend it by something like $(r^2+1)g$ where $r$ is the distance to $V$ in the tubular neighbourhood.

Comment: @s.harp: What you wrote would not be a Riemannian metric, only a pseudo-Riemannian metric, since it will vanish along the directions normal to $V$. The standard construction is the one of a "warped product".